# Grails ApplicationHolder replacement

Tags: grails

I would like to ask what should I replace ApplicationHolder to get the grailapplication. I have the following grails script to run a method in a grails service.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
import de.rvgmbh.nemesis.migration.service.MasterDataMigrationService
def ctx = ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext()
def dataSource = ctx.getBean("dataSourceSybase")
def masterDataMigrationService = new MasterDataMigrationService(dataSourceSybase: dataSource)
if (masterDataMigrationService != null) {
    masterDataMigrationService.partnerMigration() 
}
else {
  println "ist leider etwas falsches passiert"
}
```

dataSourceSybase is a spring bean in resources.groovy. What should I do to replace ApplicationHolder since it is now deprecated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If this is a script you run with the run-script command, the context is already injected into it for you.  Just use the variable ctx.  No need to define it.

Comment: yes that is script, which needs to be run by run-script command.The thing is if I want to change it to standard gant script. It doesnot work.

Comment: Then you should update your question to be more specific about what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("Bootstrap")

target(main: "master data migration service") {
// TODO: Implement script here
depends(bootstrap)
bootstrap()
def dataSource = appCtx.getBean("dataSourceSybase")
def masterDataMigrationService = new MasterDataMigrationService(dataSourceSybase: dataSource)

if (masterDataMigrationService != null) {
  masterDataMigrationService.partnerMigration()
}
else {
 println "ist leider etwas falsches passiert"
}

} 


setDefaultTarget(main)
```

The following is what I try to convert into gant script. It can not run

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("Bootstrap")

target(main: "master data migration service") {
// TODO: Implement script here
bootstrap()
def dataSource = appCtx.getBean("dataSourceSybase")
def masterDataMigrationService = new MasterDataMigrationService(dataSourceSybase: dataSource)

if (masterDataMigrationService != null) {
  masterDataMigrationService.partnerMigration()
}
else {
    println "ist leider etwas falsches passiert"
}

}
setDefaultTarget(main)
```